# Внутренний класс в теле цикла

Tags: java, ооп

Изучаю java по книге Шилда и в примере внутреннего класса в теле цикла есть объявление объекта **obj2** и обращения к методу внутреннего класса **obj2.methodInner()**

```
class outer{

  int outer_x = 100;

  void methodOuter(){
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
      class inner{
        void methodInner(){
          System.out.println("outer_x = " + outer_x);
        }
      }

      inner obj2 = new inner();
      obj2.methodInner();

    }
  }
}

class programm{

  public static void main (String args[]){
    outer obj1 = new outer();
    obj1.methodOuter();
  }
}
```

Вопрос:

Почему при перемещении этих 2х строк кода

```
inner obj2 = new inner();
obj2.methodInner();
```

в положение перед классом

```
  void methodOuter(){
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){

      inner obj2 = new inner();
      obj2.methodInner();

      class inner{
        void methodInner(){
          System.out.println("outer_x = " + outer_x);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

выдает ошибку.

код ошибки

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        inner cannot be resolved to a type
        inner cannot be resolved to a type
```

*Пишу в VSCode с плагином для Java, пробовал в IntelliJ IDEA - результат тот же*

[image: порядок выполнения инструкций]

*Вопрос не про ошибку и что с ней делать, а факт ошибки. Раз объявление объекта **obj2** и обращение к методу внутреннего класса **obj2.methodInner()** находится в области видимости цикла, почему не могу поставить перед внутренним классом? Хочу добиться выполнения 1,2,3,4,5, а не 1,4,5,2,3*

Comment: Это не зависит от того, в какой среде вы работаете. Это определяется компилятором, который, в свою очередь, должен соответствовать спецификации языка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Область видимости класса, вложенного в блок, начинается от объявления этого класса и простирается до конца блока:

> The scope of a local class declaration immediately enclosed by a block (§14.2) is
> the rest of the immediately enclosing block, including its own class declaration.

(см. [спецификацию языка](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3))

Comment: Зачем удалены из ответа замечания о нюансах языка? Разве они неверны, или понимание таких вещей вредит новичкам, или они не имеют никакого отношения к вопросу?

Comment: Приложил картинку для наглядности. Надеюсь, вопрос стал более ясным

Comment: @SergeyMaksimov Вопрос и так ясен, и ответ остается тем же. Вы, видимо, просто не поняли, что это ответ на ваш вопрос. Если сказать то же самое другими словами -- локальный класс нельзя использовать ДО его определения, точно так же, как и локальную переменную. Это правило определяется спецификацией языка, не зависит от среды разработки и обойти его невозможно.

Comment: Да, спустя время Ваш ответ уложился в голове. Спасибо